# Gsutil downloading Android review stats csv files as binary

Tags: android, google-play, gsutil

I'm trying to download the review data for my Android app.

But the files gsutil downloads are not text files!

FWIW, I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with gsutil 4.7.

Below is an example

```
stats$ gsutil cat gs://pubsite_prod_rev_xxxxxxxxx/stats/ratings/ratings_com.yyyyyyyyyy_201501_overview.csv
��
�@��uO�X���]]GD/ �FP_G�%�fם���9;:��
                                            �� �5�����sv���g�T��S;�����v�jZ}�={H0B�y�cD~M�O���wC���2F����ZI��9�.p�wM�e��p�3���Rj#^�,�²Ԍ��bY�V`�jy���^�X-�p�2��b�&jg8�+�uV�|�~�N߰����xY:}��_��t�F[�,�������F���xY:}�aY�e���|U:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran gsutil for the first time and saw the same thing - something that looks like binary rubbish. Except...

```
$ gsutil cp gs://pubsite_prod_rev_xxxx/reviews/reviews_com.yyyy.csv .
$ file reviews_com.yyyy.csv
$ reviews_com.yyyy.csv: Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with very long lines
```

So it is text, you just need to use the right tool to view it.  I managed to load it into gedit:

```
$ gedit reviews_com.yyyy.csv
```

Then save as something else.  I am sure there is a better way.

Comment: I thought UTF text would be at least partially visible. I'd never seen raw UTF-16 before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the data you have in your bucket, is encrypted or some other format. I tried to download the files in same environment and it works well for me. So i would suggest check your file contents, by just downloading it manually from the bucket.

Comment: agree with @Shobhitg . tried to replicate on a bucket I have and did not have any issues. try to upload a generic .csv and see how it behaves. I found this one, its available for free  : http://spatialkeydocs.s3.amazonaws.com/FL_insurance_sample.csv.zip

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded three .csv review files for our app and noticed the same. I'm running Mac OS X (yosemite/10.10.1) and for me the file is identified as gzipped file:

```
$ file Dec2014.csv
$ Dec2014.csv: gzip compressed data, from FAT filesystem (MS-DOS, OS/2, NT)
```

I managed to turn this into readable file by adding .zip to the end of filename and unzipping it. Then it is a perfectly ok text file for, for example, TextEdit or Numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely utf-16 encoded. You can run this to convert on the Mac:

```
iconv -f UTF-16 <file>.csv
```

Google unfortunately makes it much more complicated to get reviews than Apple does with their RSS feeds…